# Problem with a div in a calendar javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

[The calendar i made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H38p0.png)

As you see today it is the second of april but it wont show me the right selected day.

This is a link to the project.
https://github.com/dragosreal1214/Calendar_Site_FIIPractic

Comment: On stack overflow it's strongly preferred that you include the code/images in the question rather than linking to them

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use `today.getDate()` instead of `today.getDay()`.

`today.getDay()` returns of the day of the week (0-6) of a date.

```
 if(i.toString() === today.getDate().toString() &&
             today.getMonth() === currDate.getMonth() && today.getFullYear() === currDate.getFullYear()) {
                day.setAttribute("class", "today");
            }
```